# How can one make a partial index to optimize a query for a single value?

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have table `foos` with column `thing_id`.

What's the smallest index I could make for these queries?

```
select count(*) from foos where thing_id is null;
select id from foos where thing_id is null;
```

Conceptually, we just need the index to keep track of a list of primary keys which match the criteria. Is it possible/useful to create a partial index on... no columns?

I tried this and postgres considered it a syntax error:

```
create index on foos where thing_id is null;
```

This did work

```
create index on foos (thing_id) where thing_id is null;
```

But will this result in unnecessarily writing the value of thing_id (always NULL) for each row?

Comment: `CREATE INDEX idx_name ON foos ((thing_id IS NULL), id)` seems to be the most suitable for these queries. Of course you may try also `CREATE INDEX idx_name ON foos (id) WHERE thing_id IS NULL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always need a column in an index.

You could try to index a constant that occupies only one byte:

```
SELECT typname FROM pg_type WHERE typlen = 1;

 typname 
---------
 bool
 char
(2 rows)
```

If you choose `boolean`, that would be

```
CREATE INDEX ON foos ((TRUE)) WHERE thing_id IS NULL;
```

But my recommendation is to index `id`. Sure, that would make the index somewhat bigger, but your second query could use a much faster index-only scan.

Comment: gotcha, so `create index on foos (id) where thing_id is null;`

Comment: I see that I forgot the table name - I have fixed it. Yes, you got it right.